# XamDataGrid Hierarchical Structure with same Datatype

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I'm new in the XamDataGrid-Topic. Currently I'm playing around with the XamDataGrid to find out what functionality is offered.

I already have two questions:

I have hierarchical Data that looks like this:

public class TestDTO

{

public int Id { get; set; }

public string Description { get; set; }

public ObservableCollection Children { get; set; }

}

My Xaml FieldLayouts looks like this:

My xaml can't be shown...

I want to display the Data Like this:

Column Id | Column Description

- 123     | Description123
- 234     | Description234

  > > 456   | ChildDescription456
- 567     | Description567

The problem is: It seems, that just the "parentLayout" is used by the XamDataGrid. Changes in the "childLayout" are not accepted. Additionally the Column-Headers are displayed in the child-level, although the LabelLocation = Hidden. Is there a general problem when the top-level dataType is the same as the child-level?

That brings me to my next question:

Is it possible to synchronise the columns of the ParentLayout with the ones of the childLayout? So they have the same alignment but the expansion-indicator is still intended.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Any success for solving your issue ? Cause I migth be interested with your feedback. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, XamDataGrid works with `BindingList<T>`. So change your Children collection to a `BindingList<T>`. Also, did u create separate field layouts for parent and child? In the child layouts `FieldLayoutSettings` set `LabelLocation="Hidden"`

Comment: Yes I created separate field layouts and the child layout has labelloaction = hidden. The problem is that the children datatype is the same as the parent datatype. So only the parent field layout is used.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. When child datatype was different the grid worked fine. When the child datatype was the same type as the parent, it would use the parent's layout. I started adding the properties from this post:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658553/masking-child-table-of-xamdatagrid-hierarchical-grid)

It was setting the ParentFieldLayoutKey prop on the child layout that made the grid start observing the child layout.