# Masking child table of XamDataGrid Hierarchical Grid

Tags: wpf, xaml, infragistics

First here is my structure

- layer 1 >Collection of `<Objects>`
- layer 2-->Each `Object` has another collection of `Objects` inside of it

Desired result:

- The first collection is show in the datagrid with an expander next to it
- Under the expander for each row there is the second collection of objects that relate to the selected layer 1

I am successfully collapsing the unwanted fields on layer 1.

However, when you click the expander icon to view layer two on the selected object from layer 1 you see all of the fields that are dynamically generated from the object.

Question: How do you hide the fields of layer 2

```
<igWPF:XamDataGrid Theme="IGTheme" DataSource="{Binding layer1Collection}">                          
  <igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
      <igWPF:FieldLayout>
        <igWPF:FieldLayout.Fields>
           <igWPF:Field Name="val1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
           <igWPF:Field Name="val2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>                                        
           <igWPF:Field Name="val3" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
           <igWPF:Field Name="val4" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
           <igWPF:Field Name="val5" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
           <igWPF:Field Name="val6" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
           <igWPF:Field Name="val7" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
           <igWPF:Field Name="val8" Visibility="Visible"/>
           <igWPF:Field Name="val9" Visibility="Visible"/>

           <!-- This is where the second layer is-->
             <igWPF:Field Name="val10" Visibility="Visible" IsExpandable="True" Label="Details" IsSelected="True" IsPrimary="True" />                             


       </igWPF:FieldLayout.Fields>
     </igWPF:FieldLayout>
  </igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
 </igWPF:XamDataGrid>
```

Comment: You need to define a layout for the children.  If all you want to do is prevent the fields from being created, you should set AutoGenerateFields to false.  There are more details in the Define a Field Layout topic: http://help.infragistics.com/doc/WPF/Current/CLR4.0/?page=xamDataPresenter_Define_a_Field_Layout.html

Answer (score 4):

In order to mask the child grid you must create a second field layout and tie them together like this...

```
<igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
  <igWPF:FieldLayout Key="layer1">
    <igWPF:FieldLayout.Fields>
       <igWPF:Field Name="val1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
       <igWPF:Field Name="val2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>                                        
       <igWPF:Field Name="val3" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
       <igWPF:Field Name="val4" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
       <igWPF:Field Name="val5" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
       <igWPF:Field Name="val6" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
       <igWPF:Field Name="val7" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
       <igWPF:Field Name="val8" Visibility="Visible"/>
       <igWPF:Field Name="val9" Visibility="Visible"/>

       <!-- This is where the second layer is-->
         <igWPF:Field Name="details" Visibility="Visible" IsExpandable="True" Label="Details" IsSelected="True" IsPrimary="True" />                             


   </igWPF:FieldLayout.Fields>
 </igWPF:FieldLayout>
 <igWPF:FieldLayout Key="Detail" ParentFieldName="details" ParentFieldLayoutKey="layer1">
        <igWPF:FieldLayout.Fields>
              <igWPF:Field Name="L2val1" Label="L2val"/>
              <igWPF:Field Name="L2val2" Label="L2val"/>
              <igWPF:Field Name="L2val3" Label="L2val"/>
              <igWPF:Field Name="L2val4" Label="L2val"/>
              <igWPF:Field Name="L2val" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
         </igWPF:FieldLayout.Fields>
     </igWPF:FieldLayout>
  </igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
```